# How do I restrict requests made by Angularjs $resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

Let's say I want to create a resource that handles communication with a REST server, and more specifically, with a table of cards. I have it defined roughly like this:

```
$resource(... + '/cards/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
  read: { ... },
  save: { ... },
  create: { ... },
  delete: {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: rHeaders,
    params: {id: '@id'},
  }
})
```

Now if I want to delete a card with an id 12, all I have to do is to call `$delete({id: 12})`, which makes request which goes roughly like this: *DELETE .../cards/12*. This is what I want, great, **BUT** there is still a good chance of accidentally calling `$delete()` with no parameters which would result in a request like this: *DELETE .../cards*, which would delete the whole table, something that I don't want. Is there any way to make this resource a little more foolproof within the definition of the resource? Thanks.

Comment: You should avoid the wildcard deletion from your API backend not from AngularJS. What's the backend code? Change it if it doesn't receive any ID it should throw an error.

Comment: Not really answering your question but in my view `DELETE .../cards` without an ID should not be exposed at the server. Even if you remove it from your `$resource`, anyone can still just make the request by hand.

Comment: I talked to the person who does the backend and he would prefer it to stay like this. Anyone can still make a request by hand but that would hardly be an accident. I just wouldn't want to restore the testing database twice a week, especially since there are some new people around who might not be familiar with how the resource works.